# Bluetooth (HC_06) on the Attiny85

Tags: bluetooth, softwareserial, communication, attiny, attiny85

I'm trying to make a hc_06 Bluetooth controller work on the attiny85-20pu.
In the end, I want to control a stepper motor through Bluetooth.
But for now to keep it simple I'm searching for a working code that can turn a simple LED on and off or something like that.

I've searched for a code like that, and I found a few, but they all don't seem to work when I try it.
I checked if the hc_06 maybe wasn't receiving any data or maybe that my wiring was wrong, but at this point I doubt it since I've tried so many different codes and re-wired it so much that I feel like at least 1 should've worked by now

For reference, here are 2 codes I've tried so far but didn't seem to work

source1: https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/attiny85-microcontroller-bluetooth-hc-06-arduino-ide/20252/2

source2: https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/attiny85-microcontroller-bluetooth-hc-06-arduino-ide/20252/2

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> //Software Serial Port
#define TxD 0 //pin 5 de l'ATtiny à relier au pin RXD du module bluetooth (pin5)
#define RxD 1 //pin 6 de l'ATtiny à relier au pin TXD du module bluetooth (pin4)

SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);
int relais = 4; // pin 3 de l'ATtiny qui commande le relais

void setup()
{
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  blueToothSerial.begin(9600);
  //delay(2000); // délai nécessaire
  blueToothSerial.print("Bluetooth connecté !\n");
  delay(4000); //Vérifie que tous les relais sont bien inactifs après un reset
  pinMode(relais, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(relais, LOW); // ouvre le relais
}

void loop()
{
  char recvChar;
  while (1) {
    //vérifie s'il y a des données envoyées à partir du module bluetooth
    if (blueToothSerial.available()) {
      recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();
      if (recvChar == '1')
        digitalWrite(relais, HIGH);
      else
        digitalWrite(relais, LOW);
    }
  }
}
```

Or this one

```cpp
// Tiny85 y Bluetooth HC-06
// Juan A. Villalpando
// kio4.com

#include <SoftSerial.h>
#include <TinyPinChange.h>
#define LED4 4

SoftSerial Bluetooth(2, 3);
char caracter;

void setup()
{
  Bluetooth.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  while (Bluetooth.available() > 0) {
    caracter = Bluetooth.read();
    if (caracter == '1') {
      digitalWrite(LED4, HIGH);
      Bluetooth.println('E');
    }
    if (caracter == '0') {
      digitalWrite(LED4, LOW);
      Bluetooth.println('A');
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

With this code it works but only if I disconnect TX from the HC_06 to RX to the attiny85. If I do that the LED will turn on after a few seconds
and if I then send a 0 it works fine.
hopefully this helps?

````cpp
#define RxD 1
#define TxD 0

#define DEBUG_ENABLED  1
 
SoftwareSerial blueToothSerial(RxD,TxD);

int led = 4 ;
 
void setup() 
{ 
  pinMode(RxD, INPUT);
  pinMode(TxD, OUTPUT);
  setupBlueToothConnection();

  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);

 
} 
 
void loop() 
{ 
  char recvChar;
  while(1){
    //check if there's any data sent from the remote bluetooth shield
    if(blueToothSerial.available()){
      recvChar = blueToothSerial.read();

        if(recvChar==0)
          digitalWrite(4,HIGH);

        else
          digitalWrite(4,LOW); 
    }
  }
} 
 
void setupBlueToothConnection()
{
  blueToothSerial.begin(38400); //Set BluetoothBee BaudRate to default baud rate 38400
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STWMOD=0\r\n"); //set the bluetooth work in slave mode
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STNA=MAVA_bluetoothcr\r\n"); //set the bluetooth name as "HC-05"
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STOAUT=1\r\n"); // Permit Paired device to connect me
  blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+STAUTO=0\r\n"); // Auto-connection should be forbidden here

  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  //blueToothSerial.print("\r\n+INQ=1\r\n"); //make the slave bluetooth inquirable 
  blueToothSerial.print("bluetooth connected!\n");

  delay(2000); // This delay is required.
  blueToothSerial.flush();
}```
````

Comment: how is everything connected and how is it powered?

Comment: depends on which of the 2 codes you mean. but I'm pretty sure its not a wiring problem. And as for the power I'm using a Arduino uno which only use is to power the Attiny85 and hc_06.

Comment: Does the HC-06 work correctly with the Unos Serial connection? It might be configured to the wrong baudrate

Comment: Its not hooked up to an Arduino but to the attiny85 itself but I did test it on the Arduino and it works just fine. the hc_06 still receives data no problem but somehow nothing happens with that data.

Comment: Mhh, is the Attiny running at the frequency, that the compiler is expecting? If you compile lets say for an 8MHz clock frequency, but the fuses still are set to 1MHz, that would also mess with the timing of the software serial interface

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the fuses of the attiny85 but I did calculate that I should put de baud rate on 38400 if I compile it with 8MHz I'm not sure if that helps?